# Remove magentos search suggest feature?

Tags: magento

Magento's search box display a rather horrid looking/ slow loading search suggest box underneath as you type a search.

Where is the best place in the code to remove this feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could give either a try:

In Magento template’s css file, find:

`.search auto-complete`

and add:

`display: none;`

to get:

`.search-autocomplete { display: none; }`

You'll have to make sure your css gets refreshed.

`OR`

Look for this: `\template\catalogsearch\form.mini.phtml` and remove or comment out the line containing:

`searchForm.initAutocomplete(.......`

Comment: I removed the javascript as suggested.  I think this is better as it will actually remove the process entirely.  Thank you.

Comment: Comment the javascript code that you mention do the trick. And prevents the code from working, so I think is the best solution by the way. you've got my upvote ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this
In Magento folder

1. Find:

> Vendor/magento/Magento_Search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml

Copy this form.min.phtml in

1. > app/design/vendor/your_theme/Magento_Search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml

Under this file you can find the below code,make hide or remove these lines

```
data-mage-init='{"quickSearch":{
                                "formSelector":"#search_mini_form",
                                "url":"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('search/ajax/suggest', ['_secure' => $block->getRequest()->isSecure()]); ?>",
                                "destinationSelector":"#search_autocomplete"}
                           }'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `requirejs-config.js` in `your_module/view/frontend` folder
2. Add below code into js file:

   ```
   var config = {
       map: {
           '*': {
               quickSearch: 'your_module/js/disableautosuggest'
           }
       }
   };
   ```
3. Create `disableautosuggest.js` in `your_module/view/frontend/we/js` folder
4. Add below code in that js:

   ```
   define([
       'jquery',
       'jquery/ui',
       'Magento_Search/form-mini' 
   ], function($){
       $.widget('test.quickSearch', $.mage.quickSearch, {
           options: {
               minSearchLength: 200,
           },
       });
       return $.test.quickSearch;
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The neatest way of doing this is to use a Mixin to extend the original object and override the minSearchLength option. Unfortunately Alex M's method no longer works as the minSearchLength option is always set from the template's data-mage-init, irrespective of what is set in the default options. To avoid messing with templates, override the _create function in the mixin and set the minSearchLength option there.

app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Search/js/form-mini': {
                'vendor_module/js/form-mini-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/js/form-mini-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var formMiniWidgetMixin = {
        _create: function () {
            this.options.minSearchLength = 200;
            this._super();
        }
    };

    return function (targetWidget) {
        $.widget('mage.quickSearch', targetWidget, formMiniWidgetMixin);

        return $.mage.quickSearch;
    };
});
```